# Get Checkbox id from HTML markup

Tags: jquery, html

Following is my html markup. I want to get the ID from the following markup in jQuery. Please suggest how I can achieve this.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="HOWARD" onchange="checkIfCheckAll()" class="checkBoxClass">
```

Below is my code that i am using to traverse through the table and getting the checkbox's id

```
$("#tblSearch tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
                debugger;
                var this_row = $(this);
                var EligibleOrNo = $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(6)').html());//td:eq(0) means first td of this row
            });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

You just want to retrieve the ID? Based on what?  Here's an example using the checkbox class name;

```
$('.checkBoxClass').attr('id');
```

Comment: I have a table which I am looping. I have got the above as row. I just need to extract the ID so that I can check or uncheck as per my condition.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the `attr` to retrive the id, you can select the input based on the class or like `$('input[type="checkbox"]')` depending on your requirement

```js
$(function(){
  console.log($('.checkBoxClass').attr('id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="HOWARD" onchange="checkIfCheckAll()" class="checkBoxClass">
```

Answer (score 0):

This can depend on how you intend on targeting the element itself.

If you are already using an event-handler in jQuery, such as one that checks if a checkbox is checked, you could resolve the specific `id` via the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function as seen below :

```
$('.checkBoxClass').change(function(){
      // Get your id here when a given checkbox is checked
      var id = $(this).attr('id');

      // Do something
});
```

Or if you wanted to access it from your `checkIfCheckAll()` function, you could consider passing the element in using `checkIfCheckAll(this)` and simply accessing the `id` property from within your function as seen below :

```
function checkIfCheckAll(element){
    var id = element.id;
    // Use the ID here
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="HOWARD" onchange="checkIfCheckAll(this)" class="checkBoxClass">
<script>
function checkIfCheckAll(element){
    var id = element.id;
    alert(id);
}  
</script>
```

Otherwise, you could potentially have multiple checkboxes, so simply accessing the `id` element may not be as reliable as you would have to know the specific index of the element you are targeting.

**Update (post-edit)**

It appears that you are trying to resolve the ID of a given element within a specific cell. If that is the case, then you could use the `class` attribute to target that element and access its `id` via :

```
$("#tblSearch tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
   // Get the row
   var this_row = $(this);
   // Get the ID (i.e. find the checkbox in that cell and get its id)
   var EligibleOrNo = $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(6) .checkBoxClass').attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: If you already have the `<td>` element that contains your checkbox, you could simply use `this_row.find('td:eq(6) .checkBoxClass').attr('id')` to find the specific checkbox within a given cell and get its id.

Comment: Without seeing your exact markup, it would be tough to determine exactly how to handle it. If you already have the `checkIfCheckAll()` function firing when they are updated, you should be able to easily resolve it and apply your logic there. Likewise, if you needed to target all of your checkboxes (to actually check / uncheck them all), you could just use `$('.checkboxClass').each(function(){ $(this).prop('checked', yourConditionHere); });`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then one checkbox elements with same class. you can iterate over all and collect the ids in an array.

```js
var idArray = [];
$(".checkBoxClass").each(function(index,elem){
  idArray.push(elem.id)
});
console.log(idArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="HOWARD" onchange="checkIfCheckAll()" class="checkBoxClass">
```